# Installing python library matplotlib on RedHat for second python installation

Tags: rhel, python

I can't seem to find documentation on this. Matplotlib says to run:

```
sudo yum install python-matplotlib
```

which installs all the dependancies and this version of matplotlib successfully:

```
python-matplotlib.x86_64 0:0.99.1.2-1.6.amzn1
```

However, I use python2.7, separately installed. The original (and still existing) python2.6 now imports matplotlib successfully. Is there a related matplotlib package on RedHat for python2.7?

Other info:

- `which python2.6` returns `/usr/bin/python2.6`
- `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`.
- `cat /proc/version` returns
  `Linux version 3.14.23-22.44.amzn1.x86_64 ... (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) ...`

Comment: If there isn't just install with `pip` (assuming you have that installed for 2.7 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built from source. :( Surprisingly not that difficult, but ran into a lot of problems doing the interactive part (Redhat 4 is too old to have packages for most things that let you do interactive backends, I need a newer machine).

```
# get matplotlib
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.3/matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz

#uncompress
tar xvzf matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz

# open build install
# read INSTALL file for more instructions
cd matplotlib-1.4.3
python setup.py build
# actually installing needed superuser privileges
sudo python setup.py install
```

Hope this saves time for anyone else with a similar setup.

---

NOTE:

I tried what @Anthon said to do! but it didn't work very well because of the age of my OS? pip assumes some things that didn't work well for some annoying reason. I tried to use pip2.7 instead, [installed all the required dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843560/2553191), and it [broke on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663620/2553191) concerning permissions. The solution is to reset the permissions of the problem file with:

```
chmod o+x /path/to/file
```

However, it's a temporary copied file. :( During the install of matplotlib it recopies this file over, so I can't set permissions on it. Here is the place it is broken:

```
g++ ... -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.so
running install_lib
copying pylab.py -> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py'
```

This doesn't seem like the right way to do it, it's too cobbled together. Final solution to avoid all this is the start of this answer.